# Nested transactions in Mule: are they possible?

Tags: transactions, mule

I have the following flow in Mule 3.3.2:

```
<flow name="testFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint
            connector-ref="vmConnector"
            path="in">
        <vm:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </vm:inbound-endpoint>

    <transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN">
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint
                connector-ref="jdbcConnector"
                queryKey="insertTest"
        />

        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint
                connector-ref="jdbcConnector"
                queryKey="insertTest2"
        />
        <rollback-exception-strategy/>
    </transactional>

    <vm:outbound-endpoint
            connector-ref="vmConnector"
            path="outErrorQueue">
        <vm:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>
    </vm:outbound-endpoint>
 </flow>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a jdbc transaction nested into the vm transaction: any exception inside the transactional scope should trigger rollback for the jdbc transaction, propagate to the scope of the transactional flow and trigger the default exception strategy for the vm transaction. Any exception outside of the transactional scope should just trigger the default exception strategy of the flow, of course.

Reading source for e.g. `org.mule.transaction.TransactionCoordination` leads me to believe that that might work, at least if `transactional` would accept `ACTION_NOT_SUPPORTED` as action (which it does  not -- can I make it?).

What i get instead is

```
org.mule.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: A transaction is not available for this session, but transaction action is "Always Join"
at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:41)
at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
```

at the vm:outbound-endpoint.

Is there any alternative way to get what I want with Mule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the VM connector supports nested transactions.

I would try using XA for this use case as XA transactions can be suspended and resumed, which would happen at the boundaries of the `transactional` block:

```
<jbossts:transaction-manager />

<flow name="testFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint
            connector-ref="vmConnector"
            path="in">
        <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </vm:inbound-endpoint>

    <transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN">
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint
                connector-ref="jdbcConnector"
                queryKey="insertTest"
        />

        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint
                connector-ref="jdbcConnector"
                queryKey="insertTest2"
        />
        <rollback-exception-strategy/>
    </transactional>

    <vm:outbound-endpoint
            connector-ref="vmConnector"
            path="outErrorQueue">
        <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>
    </vm:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Comment: Yes, of course, XA transactions. I have to do without them, and well, if there were just a single jdbc-endpoint, I could do away with the transactional scope and give the jdbc endpoint a jdbc transaction with action NOT_SUPPORTED, which would do what i want, i think. In that situation, there is no problem at all with pushing the vm transaction on the isolated tx stack and retrieving it later. This requires no cooperation on part of the vm transaction. Of course i may be misunderstanding the mechanism.

Comment: @David, Is there a form to use +more that one resource, p.ex. DB1.MySQL + DB2.Oracle like this answer, inside `transaction` block on Mule CE 3.7?

Comment: @Muka I think you'll need EE to get the `ee:xa-transactional` block in 3.7. Not 100% sure though, you have to try it.

Comment: Yes, I tried this. But I am using Mule CE, no EE. I really would like to see an example (with String or another forms) using XA in Mule CE.

Comment: @Muka No idea what you mean by "with String or another forms" but here is the CE XA transaction doc: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xa-transactions

Comment: I wanted to say Spring. Sorry! I read some suggetions about this because Mule use Spring framework. I tried to use, but didn't get success. About the link that you posted. The example use JDBC component to access database. But this component is deprecated in Mule 3.7.There is a new componenet Database connector, but XA with this new componenet just works on Mule EE, in my tests. I does not sure if I can to use old JDBC Component in Mule CE 3.7, without have problems now and in future. I would like to know what could be the better solution in this case!

Comment: I think that deprecated transports will be removed in Mule 4, so yes, you will have problems in the future. Maybe the new strategy is to limit XA to EE in the future? I don't know, you'd rather ask MuleSoft directly in their forums: http://forums.mulesoft.com for a viable CE XA solution.